# Python can't find my custom module in a folder with __init__.py

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, streamlit

Although there are multiple posts on stack overflow about custom module not found error, but those solutions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)) didn't help in my case.

My folder structure is like this:

```
project
|-- app
|   |-- script.py
|-- src
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- file.py
```

In my `script.py` I have this code

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
from project.src.file import func
```

Using VS Code in a windows7 machine, I changed the directory to `project`, and activated a conda virtual environment, then executed the code `streamlit run app\script.py`, I got this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

Changing the script to `from src.file import func` caused this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Could someone please explain what happened? Why Python couldn't find my custom module even though I had the required `__init__.py` in the folder `src`.

Comment: If it's not windows, you'll want to run app/script.py (forward-)slash, not backslash. If your current directory is project, then your module is src.file, not project.src.file. And project is not a package because there's no _ _ init _ _.py in it, only in its subdir.

Comment: @YuriFeldman, my machine is a windows 7. Changing to `from src.file import func` didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Then I would check that file.py contains a func and that your current dir is indeed project (import os; print(os.getcwd()) before the import). The latter is actually the prime suspect. As with any other programming proejct I would also make sure that its path (all the way from partition root) does not contain non-ASCII characters (e.g. your username), and also not spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the import in *script.py* to

```py
from src.file import func
```

and run it in the *project* directory using

```
python -m app.script
```

---

Since you're using `streamlit` and apparently it doesn't support running modules, you can try the method provided in [this Github issue](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/662):

1. Create a file named *run.py* inside your project directory with the following contents:

```
import runpy

runpy.run_module("app.script", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)
```

2. Run the streamlit command:

```
streamlit run run.py
```

Comment: I have to run the `script.py` using command `streamlit run...`. When I tried `streamlit run -m app.script` as per your suggestion, I got this error `no such option: -m`

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks enzo. I'll try your suggestion later but my main question was why Python couldn't find my custom module although I have the required `__init__.py` in the `src` folder.

Comment: This is not related with Python, but with the streamlit library. You're structuring your project in modules, therefore it should be run using `python -m`. Since streamlit only allows to run a single file, the import error appears.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you meant by a single file? The script also import 2 other "files" (pandas and streamlit) but the error only happened with my custom module.

Comment: When you run `streamlit run file.py`, you're running a single file called *file.py*. When you run `python -m some.module`, you're running a single module called *some.module*. streamlit [can't run modules yet](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/662) (i.e. you can't run `streamlit run -m some.module` as you've already tried), only files.

Comment: Given that your project is structured in modules and streamlit can't run modules, streamlit can't run your custom module and gives the import error you received. This is not a issue with Python: if you run `python -m app.script` as the first part of my answer describes, you'll see that the module is run successfully. Since I'm assuming you need to use streamlit, you must use a workaround, as the second part of my answer describes.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that the python interpreter in my VS Code didn't know the path of my `project` folder.

Following [this suggestion](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-fix-modulenotfounderror-and-importerror-248ce5b69b1c), I set the PYTHONPATH in my VS Code as follows:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;path\to\the\folder\project
```

with the code in script.py as `from src.file import func`.

the command `streamlit run app\script.py` then worked without errors.